# Should my public ip and elastic ip same in amazon aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, amazon-route53, amazon-ecs

I have two instances:

1. 1st instance has same Public IP and Elastic IP
2. 2nd instance has only Public IP address but i can't see "same Elastic IP"

I can see my website on Public IP address and on my domain.
Confused a lot What should i do next.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Few basics about IP Addresses in AWS.

**Private IP** : Automatically provided by AWS which will remain constant as long as the instance is placed in the VPC / Subnet. [Will live through instance start and stop, but will be released once the instance is terminated]. Scope of the IP is only inside / through the VPC.

**Public IP** : Optional IP attached to the instance during the start up along side with Private IP. Can be reached from the entire internet. During the events of Start / Stop of the instance, the Public IPs tend to change. You can also optionally not enable having Public IP being attached to the instance and have explicit Elastic IP be attached.

**Elastic IP** : Elastic IP (EIP) addresses are internet accessible scope IPs. You request for an Elastic IP and you own that IP for as long as you want. The same IP can be attached, detached and reattached to any EC2 instance. In the event of attaching EIP to an instance, the Public IP is replaced by the Elastic IP.

So to answer your question, please  Allocate a new EIP and attach it to the 2nd instance.